# Reduce number of plots in D3 Scatterplot Matrix

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I would like to reduce the number of plots in a D3 scatterplot matrix to just 4. I am using https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063663 as my initial template. I have my data set up in http://plnkr.co/edit/lySDnd58vUlelRKmk20S?p=preview. Ideally I want only the plots on the top, setting up only one Y-Axis Label (Homicides per 1000) with the x-axis changing to each subsequent plot. Something similar to this quick mockup in paint. https://postimg.org/image/7638jvln3/

I was sure it would have been controlled somewhere in here, but I realized I was a bit lost. If anyone is able to help me set this up, it will be greatly appreaciated!

```
 svg.selectAll(".x.axis")
  .data(traits)
  .enter().append("g")
  .attr("class", "x axis")
  .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(" + (n - i - 1) * size + ",0)"; })
  .each(function(d) { x.domain(domainByTrait[d]); d3.select(this).call(xAxis); });

svg.selectAll(".y.axis")
  .data(traits)
  .enter().append("g")
  .attr("class", "y axis")
  .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(0," + i * size + ")"; })
  .each(function(d) { y.domain(domainByTrait[d]);d3.select(this).call(yAxis); });


var cell = svg.selectAll(".cell")
  .data(cross(traits, traits))
  .enter().append("g")
  .attr("class", "cell")
  .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + (n - d.i - 1) * size + "," + d.j * size + ")"; })
  .each(plot);
```

One last question, is it possible to get a y-axis title to appear. When I add the code below, everything rescaled and the data disappeared.

```
svg.append("text")
    .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
    .attr("y", 0 - margin.left)
    .attr("x",0 - (height / 2))
    .attr("dy", "1em")
    .style("text-anchor", "middle")
    .style("font-size", "12px")
    .text("Homicides per 1,000");
```

Comment: A matrix plot is a grid where each variable is plotted against each other variable.  For instance, the top row, is Homicides plotted by %AF, Median household, Unemployment, HS diploma, and finally itself.  Sounds like you, though want only one row.  Is that just each of them plotted by Homicides?

Comment: Correct, I want to have one row all plotted by Homicides. I initially built this to show everything, but it was requested that I reduce it to one row. I was hoping it might be possible using the original I had put together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is indeed possible using the same code.  A little strange, but possible:

```
  // keep similar calucations
  var domainByTrait = {},
    traits = d3.keys(data[0]).filter(function(d) { return d !== "name"; }),
    n = traits.length - 1;

  traits.forEach(function(trait) {
    domainByTrait[trait] = d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d[trait];   });
  });

  // reset traits to ones you care about
  var traits = ["% Holding Only HS Diploma", "Unemployement Rate", "Median Household Value ($10k)", "% African American"];

  // chane xAxis ticks to 1, not n
  xAxis.tickSize(size * 1);
  yAxis.tickSize(-size * n);

 ...

 // modify y axis to only Homicides
 svg.selectAll(".y.axis")
  .data(["Homicides per 1000 people"])
  .enter().append("g")
  ...

// modify cross-product
var cell = svg.selectAll(".cell")
  .data(cross(traits, ["Homicides per 1000 people"]))
  .enter().append("g")
  ...

// remove filter on text titltes
cell
  //.filter(function(d) { return d.i === d.j; })
  .append("text")
  ...
```

Update [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/vubfqdF3t7X7mpyIpH55?p=preview).

Comment: This is awesome! Thank you so much for the help! One last question, is it possible to get a y-axis title to appear. When I add the code below, everything rescaled and the data disappeared. See full comment below.

Comment: @HowardSmith, see this [update here](http://plnkr.co/edit/vubfqdF3t7X7mpyIpH55?p=preview).  I think that looks nice.

Comment: @HowardSmith, also, it's frown-upon on StackOverflow to ask additional question/supply additional information in an answer.  You should delete that and edit your question with the additional information.

Comment: I see it was a bit more than just the straightforward approach I posted. Really appreciate the help! And thanks for the heads up on the additional question and how to post it. I went ahead and edited it.